# how to save pdf in directory laravel 4.2 using dompdf

Tags: php, laravel-4, dompdf

i have followed this example [laravel-4-create-pdf-use-dompdf](https://imron02.wordpress.com/2014/06/08/laravel-4-create-pdf-use-dompdf/):

i want to save pdf in directory not pdf preview in the browser.

My current code:

```
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf');
    $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Hello World!!</h1>');
    return $pdf->stream("order_email.pdf");
```

but what this code is doing, it shows my "Hello World" text as PDF in the browser but not saving "order_email.pdf" anywhere in my working directory.

Comment: Generally you can't save files to a clients machine from the browser.  They need to save it on their own.

Comment: @bowlturner i didn't say it, pdf will save in server directory and will email to user.

Comment: you can check this link for better solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795346/how-to-save-dompdf-file-to-storage-and-name-the-file-dynamicly-in-laravel/74942859#74942859

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dompdf's [`stream()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.1/lib/class.pdf.php#L3092) method always sends to the browser. If you want to capture the output and save to a file you should use the [`output()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.1/lib/class.pdf.php#L1843) method instead.

```
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Hello World!!</h1>');
file_put_contents("order_email.pdf", $pdf->output());
```

Comment: i also need help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894283/how-to-add-custom-dynamic-text-footer-in-laravel-4-2-using-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

i also found one more method to save it.

```
$pdf->save('order_email.pdf');
```

Comment: Where does dompdf saves file in laravel? in public folder?