# how to add custom dynamic text footer in laravel 4.2 using dompdf

Tags: laravel-4, dompdf

i have followed this example [laravel-4-create-pdf-use-dompdf](https://imron02.wordpress.com/2014/06/08/laravel-4-create-pdf-use-dompdf/):

how to add custom dynamic footer

```
 $dompdf = \App::make('dompdf');
 $dompdf->loadHTML('<h1>naeem World!!</h1>');
```

anyone do have idea? or please suggest,

i also have followed this solution [DOMPDF add a header and footer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/dompdf)  but it doesn't work correctly.

**Edited:**

i want `$db_data['footer_text']` to be footer text to all the pages dynamically, its coming form database.

Comment: Can you expand on your code sample to show what you've tried? It doesn't indicate any kind of header/footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from the link you provided should be enough. You just need to craft a more complete HTML document.

```
$html = <<<EOT
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @page { margin-bottom: 50px; }
      .footer { position: fixed; bottom: -50px; margin: 10px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>naeem World!!</h1>
    <h2>section 1</h2>
    <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
    <div class="footer">{$db_data['footer_text']}</div>
    <h2>section 2</h2>
  </body>
  </html>
EOT;
$dompdf = \App::make('dompdf');
$dompdf->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: actually i need footer, and i have like 10 pages of text for pdf, footer come to start from 2nd page or 3rd page, it is not reliable with css

Comment: Sorry, you did say footer. I updated the code sample. It's pretty much the same, you just vary the positioning/margin information. As for starting with page 2 or 3, if you want the footer to start with specific content just add it to your document at that point. They way dompdf currently parses documents fixed-position content begins on the page where it is first encountered.